# installing software has encountered error in the eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, liferay

i have one problem 
i have setup of the liferay 
i download the eclipse mars for the development but whenever i go to eclipse market place to download plugi for the liferay i have encounter the following error .

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/stable/tools/plugins/com.liferay.ide.doc_2.2.3.201505281145-ga4.jar.
connect timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems somehow Eclipse is trying to interpret the URL shown in the error **as a repository**, which it is not.

To check this, go to `Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites`. If you find that URL in the list, remove it.

That jar file actually exists and can be downloaded OK - you may want to try this from your machine, too.

When you try again installing from the MarketPlace and if again you get an error, I'd expect that error to show up under "Errors" in https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liferay-ide. Here you also have the opportunity to write a comment which should get the attention of the solution provider.